# How to compare objects of 2 different Array?

Tags: android

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject Jasonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    mcategory_id=Jasonobject.getString("category_id");
    vaccinationData.setmCategory_id(mcategory_id);
    items.add(vaccinationData);
}

for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
    CategoryModelClass vaccinationData1=new 
    CategoryModelClass();
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
    scategory_id=jsonObject1.getString("category_id");
    vaccinationData1.setmCategory_id(scategory_id);
    items.add(vaccinationData);
}
```

I have to compare value of mcategory_id and scategory_id from 2 different array list. How can I compare these 2 value? What logic should I use for this?

Comment: Read about **Jeckson** or **JSONAssert**

Comment: Can you give more detail. I don't see the ArrayLists in the code. There seems to be only one, items, where you collect all vaccinationData

Comment: Here i am using 2 different array list from json.I have to compare mcategory_id and scategory_id....please check my code

Comment: vaccinationData  is an object of model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about the order, you can use the List's "equals" method.

```
List mcategoryIdList = new ArrayList();
List scategoryIdList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    //retrieve json objects
    JSONObject Jasonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);

    //add to lists
    mcategoryIdList.add(Jasonobject.getString("category_id"));
    scategoryIdList.add(jsonObject1.getString("category_id"))
}

//now you can compare both
if(mcategoryIdList.equals(scategoryIdList)){
    //they're equal
}else{
    //they're not equal
}
```

If you don't care about the order, use Sets:

```
Set mcategoryIdSet = new HashSet();
Set scategoryIdSet = new HashSet();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    //retrieve json objects
    JSONObject Jasonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);

    //add to sets
    mcategoryIdSet.add(Jasonobject.getString("category_id"));
    scategoryIdSet.add(jsonObject1.getString("category_id"))
}

//now you can compare both
if(mcategoryIdSet.equals(scategoryIdSet)){
    //they're equal
}else{
    //they're not equal
}
```